# update list property in listTicker function every X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I am attempting to create a ticker that fades in and out the objects in an array using the jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut function. I referenced someone else's code and was able to get it working for the most part. What I would like to do now is get the list property of listTicker to update every X number of seconds and move to the next array. I assume I must use a for loop somehow but I just cant seem to figure out how to implement it.

Below is what I was able to get working:

```
var listTicker = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        list: [],
        startIndex:0,
        interval: 3 * 1000,
    }   
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var listTickerInner = function(index) {

        if (options.list.length == 0) return;

        if (!index || index < 0 || index > options.list.length) index = 0;

        var value= options.list[index];

        options.trickerPanel.fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).html(value).fadeIn();
        });

        var nextIndex = (index + 1) % options.list.length;

        setTimeout(function() {
            listTickerInner(nextIndex);
        }, options.interval);

    };

    listTickerInner(options.startIndex);
};

var textlist = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
var textlist2 = new Array("Dell", "HP", "Toshiba");
var textlist3 = new Array("John", "Dave", "Greg");
var currentlist = new Array(textlist, textlist2, textlist3);

$(function() {
    listTicker({
        list: currentlist[0] ,
        startIndex:0,
        trickerPanel: $('#expression'),
        interval: 3 * 1000,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% happy with the organization/separation of this code, but it achieves the objective:

http://jsfiddle.net/49Y8s/

```
    options.trickerPanel.fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html(value).fadeIn();

        var nextItemIndex = (index+1) < currentList.length ? (index+1) : 0;
        var nextListIndex = (function(){
            var val = listIndex;

            if(nextItemIndex==0){
                val = listIndex+1;
            }

            if(val >= options.lists.length){
                val = 0;
            }

            return val;
        })();

        setTimeout(function() {
            listTickerInner(nextListIndex,nextItemIndex);
        }, options.interval);
    });
```